# Trying to access functions from MainActivity

Tags: android, import

I am trying to access MainActivity function to my another java class. But i am not able to use these function. Please tell me what else need to be added to get it access.

My code: 
Where i am trying to access my MainActivity

```
   package com.example.musicplayer;

  **import com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity;**
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class current_song extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


     MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

     Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.songplay_page);

     if(extra != null){
         String song_name = extra.getString("song_name");
         TextView textchange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);
         textchange.setText(song_name);
         textchange.setSelected(true);
     }       

     Button btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause_btn);
     btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);    

     Button btn_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
     btn_next.setOnClickListener(this);

     Button btn_prv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
     btn_prv.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Onclick ()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.pause_btn:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ma.pause();
        break;

        case R.id.next_btn:
            ma.next();
        break;

        case R.id.prv_btn:
            ma.prv();
        break;

    }

}

   }
```

Comment: Which function do you want to call? from where?

Comment: what issue are you getting in this ?

Comment: I think you should use Handler and pass sendMessage() to handler in MainActivity and call the function in that handler's handleMessage() method accordingly depending on message.

Comment: If you're trying to call another Activity from this Activity you would have to broadcast an intent rather than just saying new MyActivity. If that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: then if i use intent rather than MyActivity. How can i specify which function should get called.

Comment: @Anu0042 : instead of calling method by creating Activity instance  create a separate common class for sharing all methods between Application components

Comment: @Anu0042 What method are you trying to call in which activity? But this guy above me has it right. Using The Model View Controller approach to it is usually the best policy.

Comment: i have some methods defined by me stop(), next(), pri() i am trying to access these methods when i click on each button. If you think that "creating a separate common class for sharing all methods" can you please show me 1 example bec i don't know how to access a method from 1 activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that MainActivity has a zero argument constructor and the access specifier for pause , next and prv function is public.

Answer (score 0):

In response to "*i have some methods defined by me stop(), next(), pri() i am trying to access these methods when i click on each button. If you think that "creating a separate common class for sharing all methods" can you please show me 1 example bec i don't know how to access a method from 1 activity to another.* "

```
public class myController{

private MyActivity m;

public myController(MyActivity m){
   this.m = m;
}

public void stop(){
   m.stop;
}

}
```

In other classes you initialize in the main activity and pass it the controller object so it can call the stop method